Is there a linear transformation mapping $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$ carrying one plane to another?
Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ defined by $U=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3:2x+3y+4z=0\}$ and $V=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3:x+2y+5z=0\}$.Which of the following statements are true?

$(1)$.There exists an invertible linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T(U)=V$.$(2$).There does not exists any invertible linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T(V)=U$.$(3)$.There exists a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T(U)\cap V\neq \{0\}$ and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is not the product of linear polynomials with real coefficients.$(4)$.There exists a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T(U)=V$ and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ vanishes at $1$.


One can obtain with simple computation that the set $\\{(\frac {-3}{2},1,0),(-2,0,1)\\}$ can be taken as the basis of $U$ and the set $\\{(-2,1,0),(-5,0,1)\\}$ can be taken as the basis of $V$. $\\{(\frac {-3}{2},1,0),(-2,0,1),(0,0,1)\\}$ and $\\{(-2,1,0),(-5,0,1),(0,0,1)\\}$ can be taken as the basis of $\Bbb R^3$.Define a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T((\frac {-3}{2},1,0))=(-2,1,0)$,$T((-2,0,1))=(-5,0,1)$,$T((0,0,1))=(0,0,1)$.Then T is invertible s.t. $T(U)=V$ and $(0,0,1)$ as an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$.Therefore option (1) and (4) are correct.For option(2):As $T$ is invertible, hence define $S=T^{-1}$ then $S$ is invertible s.t. $S(V)=U$
.So option(2) is incorrect.For option(3) I have calculated $U\cap V$ which comes out to be a subspace of dimension $1$ generated by $\\{(7,-6,1)\\}$.Now if we define a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ s.t. $T((\frac {-3}{2},1,0))=(-2,1,0)$,$T((7,-6,1))=(7,-6,1)$,$T((0,0,1))=(0,0,1)$.Then $T(U)\cap V\neq \{0\}$ and $(7,-6,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ are eigenvectors of $T$ associated with eigenvalue $1$.From here I do not have any idea how to proceed.Please someone guide.

choose some rotation matrix $T \in SO(3)$ with $TU = V$. $T$ is not diagonalizable so the characteristic polynomial is not the product of linear polynomials with real coefficients.

If $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is any invertible linear map, then $\dim(T(U)) = \dim(U) = 2$. Since $\dim(V) = 2$, we must have $\dim(T(U) \cap V) \ge 1$. So to establish (3), you just have to show that there exists an invertible $T$ whose characteristic polynomial is not the product of linear polynomials with real coefficients. Can you come up with an example of such a linear map?

that is what i am looking for.

@SandeepTiwari One such matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \ 1 & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Nice.Thank you for your valuable comment.

Without getting into coordinate specifics, $T$ the linear transformation could just project orthogonally onto $V$, followed by rotation around axis $\langle1,2,5\rangle$ (a normal vector of $V$) by some angle that is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.
That meets all of the conditions.

$T(U)$ is actually inside $V$, so $T(U)\cap V=T(U)$, and is larger than $\{0\}$ because $U$ is two-diminsional and the kernel of $T$ has dimension $1$
It is clear that $T$ has an eigenvalue $0$ and two non-real complex conjugate eigenvalues, because $T$ rotates vectors that start in the plane $V$ by a nontrivial angle. So since $T$ does not have three real eigenvalues, its characteristic polynomial is not the product of three real linear polynomials.

